# Admob ads not showing when internet connect is regain, Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, admob, ads

In my game, I use Admob ads and they work fine. But if I disable the internet during gameplay and enable it again, no ads appear.

I want to solve this issue. Players might disable and enable again the internet during gameplay. I want it to show ads whenever there is an internet connection.

I am sharing with you the whole script for running the ads.

Thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static AdManager instance;
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    

     #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string bannerAdUnitId = "";

        string interstitialAdUnitId = "";
        
        string rewardedAdUnitId = "";

    #else
        string bannerAdUnitId = "unexpected_platform";

        string interstitialAdUnitId = "unexpected_platform";

        string rewardedAdUnitId = "unexpected_platform";

    #endif

    void Awake()
    {
        if(instance != null && instance != this){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else{
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void Start() {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

        RequestBannerAd();

        RequestInterstitialAd();

        RequestRewardedAd();
    }

    //BANNER
    public void RequestBannerAd(){
        if (bannerView != null)
            bannerView.Destroy();
        
        else{
            bannerView = new BannerView(bannerAdUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);

            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

            bannerView.LoadAd(request);
        }
    }

    //INTERSTIAL

    private void RequestInterstitialAd(){
        if(interstitialAd != null)
            interstitialAd.Destroy();

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(interstitialAdUnitId);

        interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitialAd(){
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.Show();
        }
        else{
            UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
                RequestInterstitialAd();
                FindObjectOfType<GameManagement>().InterstialAdClosed();
            });
        }
    }

    public void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
            RequestInterstitialAd();
            FindObjectOfType<GameManagement>().InterstialAdClosed();
        });
    }

    //REWARDED

    public void RequestRewardedAd(){
        if(rewardedAd != null)
            rewardedAd.Destroy();

        rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(rewardedAdUnitId);

        // Called when the user should be rewarded for interacting with the ad.
        this.rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;
        // Called when an ad request failed to show.
        rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
        // Called when the ad is closed.
        rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += HandleRewardedAdClosed;

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAd(){
        if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded()) {
            rewardedAd.Show();
        }
        else{
            UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
                RequestRewardedAd();
                FindObjectOfType<GameManagement>().RewardedAdCouldntLoaded();
            });
        }
    }

    public void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward args)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
            RequestRewardedAd();
            FindObjectOfType<GameManagement>().GiveReward();
        });
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
            RequestRewardedAd();
            FindObjectOfType<GameManagement>().RewardedAdCouldntLoaded();
        });
    }

    public void HandleRewardedAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(()=>{
            RequestRewardedAd();
        });
    }

}
```